# pasar un dato a través de comunicación de componentes Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, eventos, vuetify, props, web-components

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar los eventos PROPS de Vuejs, lo que quiero lograr es poder pasar un dato del componente padre al hijo.

Pero el problema es el siguiente...

Tengo este botón que simplemente cambia el estado de **dialog = true** y me tendría que permitir abrir el MODAL (el cual se encuentra en otro componente)

**componente producto**

```
<v-btn color="deep-purple accent-4" dark @click="dialog = true">
     Crear Nuevo producto
</v-btn>

<Modal :activador="dialog"/>

<script>
import Modal from './agregarProducto';
export default {
name: 'Producto',
components: {
    Modal
},
data() {
    return {
       dialog: false, 
    }
},}
</script>
```

**componente Modal**

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog"  persistent max-width="600px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">Nuevo Producto</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <!-- formulario -->
            <v-form @submit.prevent="">
                <v-card-text scrollable>
                    <v-container>
                        <v-row>
                            <h3>{{activador}}</h3>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-form>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>

<script>
export default {
name: 'Modal',
props: ['activador'],
data() {
    return {
        dialog: this.activador
    }
},}
</script>
```

entonces mi componente padre es (Producto) y mi componente hijo es (modal)
a la hora de hacer click, **dialog** tendría que ser true y abrir mi modal pero no funciona porque la comunicación solo manda **dialog = false** y no escucha los cambios del componente padre

Comment: No conozco vuetify, pero se me ocurre que podés usar un `watcher` que mire esa `prop` y modifique el valor que tenés en `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta respuesta es solo para informarles que ya pude solucionarlo de una forma más simple.

no se porque razón al intentar mandar un dato Booleano para poder **activar un modal** este tiene tanto conflicto, tal vez solo sea por vuetify o no lose.

la SOLUCION que realice fue pasar el botón **CREAR NUEVO PRODUCTO** al componente Modal y de esa forma me anda perfecto.

```
<div>
    <v-btn color="deep-purple accent-4" dark @click="dialog = true">
        Crear Nuevo producto
    </v-btn>

    <v-dialog v-model="dialog"  persistent max-width="600px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">Nuevo Producto</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <!-- formulario -->
            <v-form @submit.prevent="">
                <v-card-text scrollable>
                    <v-container>
                        <v-row>
                            <v-btn @click="dialog = false">Cerrar</v-btn>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-form>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</div>

<script>
export default {
name: 'Modal',
data() {
    return {
        dialog: false
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Y para que el diseño se mantenga, solo mover la etiqueta **Modal** dentro de mi **v-card-title**

```
<v-card-title>
<!-- boton de crear -->                
  <Modal/>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
</v-card-title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como el valor dialog esta dentro de data no se actualiza, a dialog podrias asignarle directamente el valor de la prop 'activador' sin la asignacion de data, o si necesitas usar una variable para eso bien podrias actualizar eso con alguna de las siguientes opciones para mantener la reactividad

1

```
mounted(){
    this.dialog=this.activador;
}
```

2

```
computed(){
   dialog(){
        return this.activador;
   }
}
```

de esta manera mantienes la reactividad que necesitas para que el componente funcione correctamente.

Comment: Hola seguí tu consejo y me paso lo siguiente, a la hora de usar el **Mounted** sigue sin enviar el dato true al hacer click en el botón.

y el método **Computed** 
me tira este error (Invalid value for option "computed": expected an Object, but got Function.)